# Does Outlook need to be installed on server for Outlook Interop to work properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, ms-office

I am trying to open an email in Outlook from within a .NET application.  When I run everything on my local machine it works just fine.  When I deploy out to an IIS8 server I get an error on loading of the page.  Does Outlook need to be installed on the server as well as the local client or does it just need to be on the client?  When I comment out the below code everything loads just fine.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

protected void passdownBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
    {
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("EXEC SvcGridEmail", conn);

        conn.Open();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string body = (string)comm.ExecuteScalar();

        conn.Close();

        string address = "bogus@email.com";

        string time = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy HH:mm}", System.DateTime.Now);
        string subject = "Service Jobs Passdown @ " + time;

        Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = (Outlook._MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        oMailItem.To = address;
        oMailItem.HTMLBody = body;
        oMailItem.Subject = subject;
        oMailItem.Display(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Outlook needs to be installed on any machine where code using `Outlook.Application` runs.   Running any Office application from ASP.Net is strongly advised against.  Use `SmtpClient()` to send email, it has no dependencies on Outlook/Office.

Comment: Can I still "que" up an email from there?  My customer wants a new Outlook window opened with the body, subject and to line filled out but does not want it sent automatically.  Are there any reasons other than the dependency on Outlook being installed on why it is not advised to do it this way?

Comment: If this is Asp.net then even if Outlook were installed a user would never be able to interact with its Windows as it would run isolated on the server. Its unclear what you want.

Comment: My customer wants me to pull information from a SQL server into an email where they can edit the information before it is sent.  I have a stored procedure that returns an HTML table with data in it that is pasted into the body of the email along with a subject and To address already in there.  Looking at the SmtpClient class I don't think it will allow my customer to edit some of the information before it is sent, will it?

Comment: You would show them the data to edit in an intermediate stage form, then email that when it was submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it absolutely has to be installed. Outlook != Exchange.

You're using Outlook to automate "Outlook the application" - How can you do that if it isn't installed?

Automating Exchange is another story.

Comment: Is there any way to install a specific DLL on the server to "spoof" that Outlook is installed but still allow the user to click on a button that would generate the Outlook screen on their local machine?

Comment: If you want to open Outlook locally then what is the reason to install something on a server? Typically you cannot open desktop applications through server code for very obvious security reasons. If it is an intranet application and all users use IE - you can try to use ActiveX, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776672/opening-outlook-through-javascript another way is to configure Outlook as a default email client and use javascript+"mailto:"

Comment: This is on a webpage hosted on an IIS8 server.  I need a button that the user can click on that will open an email with the body filled out with information that can be edited.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any reasons other than the dependency on Outlook being installed

1. nonsense

   1.1. when you run it on your box - it starts Outlook using your account with your permissions, when running on server under ASP.NET account - it may not open any account even Outlook will be installed there

   1.2. how do you want to see a server application (Outlook) within an ASP.NET website, which works within a browser window?

   1.3 sending an email message does not require Outlook. See [How Can i Send Mail Through Exchange Server by using SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417344/how-can-i-send-mail-through-exchange-server-by-using-smtp) If message needs to be modified before being sent - create a webform.
2. licensing (I bet your organization has no server licence for MS Office)

Answer (score 0):

As the others have told you Outlook must be installed if you want to use `Outlook.Application`.

However, from your comments I read that you want to open an Outlook instance on the client, not on your server. This is not possible using `Outlook.Application`. As I see it you have two possibilities:

1. Follow the suggestion of @Alex K.
2. Create a [mailto link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_links_mailto_subject) for your customer. If your customer clicks it it will open the default mailing program (does not need to be Outlook) on your customer's machine with the content you have defined.